# TVOS adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused Size

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, tvos, apple-tv

Is it possible to adjust the size/frame of a ImageView when focused using `imgView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true` ?

Been scouring the webs but can't find anything that would set the zoom size of the effect, seems to just be some default value.

Comment: I think you should implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't do that. And I think Apple doesn't allow doing so for a reason.

There are very [detailed human interface guidelines for tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/). They recommend spacing and item size for a grid layout with different number of columns, so that the viewing experience is optimal:

> The following grid layouts provide an optimal viewing experience. Be
>   sure to use appropriate spacing between unfocused rows and columns to
>   prevent overlap when an item is brought into focus.

I guess the "default" frame for the focused `UIImageView` takes these recommended item sizes into account. And Apple doesn't allow to change it, because it might cause issues, like other grid items being overlapped.

So you can't modify the frame of focused `UIImageView`, but you can *access* it indirectly - by using `focusedFrameGuide` [property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1627691-focusedframeguide).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust size via imgView.transform. If your imgView inside another view (e.g. inside `UICollectionViewCell`) you can use code below to scale down image by 10% when receiving focus

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    if context.nextFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.imgView.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    if context.previouslyFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.imgView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Also you can calculate system focus scale for `UIImageView` with `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true` with next code:

```
let xScale = imgView.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame.size.width / imgView.frame.size.width 
let yScale = imgView.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame.size.height / imgView.frame.size.height
```

If you want to remove scale when focusing on `UIImageView` with `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true` use:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    let xScale = imgView.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame.size.width / imgView.frame.size.width 
    let yScale = imgView.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame.size.height / imgView.frame.size.height 
    if context.nextFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.imgView.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 1 / xScale, y: 1 / yScale)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    if context.previouslyFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.imgView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to set `clipsToBounds = false` on `UIImageView`

Comment: An amazing answer. There seems to be an overwhelming problem at the moment with tvOS , where, images simply won't scaleToFIt (or scaleToFill) inside both UIButton and UIImageView.  They just center to their natural size and won't scale down.  Have you guys seen this ???